# How does one compare specific key-values within a nested object / array structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, comparison

i have two arrays as follows

```
array1 = {name:"John",surname:"doe",reference:[{name:"jane",surname:"smith",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]},{name:"kate",surname:"post",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]}],id:"12364",weight:"50",Oid:"456978",code:"12"}

array2 =  {name:"John",surname:"doe",reference:[{name:"jane",surname:"smith,array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]"},{name:"kate",surname:"post",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]}],id:"4589632",weight:50,policy:"745896",result:"test",documents:"no",launch:"no"}
```

as you can see both of my lengths of arrays dont match so i can not compare them both.

I would like to compare only certain objects from array 1 and array 2.
for example only the objects that i require

```
array1
name:"John"
surname:"doe"
reference:[{name:"jane",surname:"smith",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]},{name:"kate",surname:"post",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]}]
weight:"50"

array 2
name:"John"
surname:"doe"
reference:[{name:"jane",surname:"smith",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]},{name:"kate",surname:"post",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]}]
weight:50
```

i only want to compare the above objects key values so the above would return true

if i had

```
 array1
    name:"John"
    surname:"doe"
    reference:[{name:"jane",surname:"smith",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]},{name:"kate",surname:"post",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:12}]}]
    weight:"12"

array 2
name:"John"
surname:"Petter"
reference:[{name:"jane",surname:"smith",array:[{name:"test",surname:"t2",position:12}]},{name:"kate",surname:"Knight",array:[{name:"test",surname:"test",position:14}]}]
weight:50
```

the above would be false.

how can i achieve this? how can i filter/loop through them to only compare the above mentioned values.

Comment: Any reason why weight is sometimes a number and sometimes a string?

Comment: when array 2 is been returned from the db its been returned as a number, and array 1 is been returned from the user

Comment: How do you know which items to compare? by name?

Comment: @StavSheiz yes by the object names i specified above,its only those objects,that i want to compare its values

Comment: I think I understand now. You want to compare objects, not arrays, and only compare some of their properties?

Comment: yes,but they belong to the 2 arrays,the objects with in the arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that will do the check.

---

**Notes :**

- We use `==` for comparaison because in your example `weight: 50` is to be equals with `weight: '50'` (string and number).
- The function also compare the inner array `reference` using the same keys to compare.

---

```js
function compareObjects(obj1, obj2, keysToCompare) {
  return keysToCompare.every(x => obj1[x] instanceof Array ?
    obj1[x].every((y, yi) => compareObjects(y, obj2[x][yi], Object.keys(y))) :
    obj1[x] == obj2[x]);
}

// Nothing is different - should work
console.log(compareObjects({
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
      name: 'jane',
      surname: 'smith',
    },
    {
      name: 'kate',
      surname: 'post'
    },
  ],
  id: '12364',
  weight: '50',
  Oid: '456978',
  code: '12',
}, {
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
    name: 'jane',
    surname: 'smith',
  }, {
    name: 'kate',
    surname: 'post',
  }],
  id: '4589632',
  weight: 50,
  policy: '745896',
  result: 'test',
  documents: 'no',
  launch: 'no',
}, [
  'name',
  'surname',
  'reference',
  'weight',
]));

// One key is different - should fail
console.log(compareObjects({
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
    name: 'jane',
    surname: 'smith',
  }, {
    name: 'kate',
    surname: 'post',
  }],
  id: '12364',
  weight: '50',
  Oid: '456978',
  code: '12',
}, {
  name: 'John',
  // This value is different
  surname: 'FOOL',
  reference: [{
    name: 'jane',
    surname: 'smith',
  }, {
    name: 'kate',
    surname: 'post',
  }],
  id: '4589632',
  weight: 50,
  policy: '745896',
  result: 'test',
  documents: 'no',
  launch: 'no',
}, [
  'name',
  'surname',
  'reference',
  'weight',
]));

// One key is different - should fail
console.log(compareObjects({
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
    name: 'jane',
    surname: 'smith',
  }, {
    name: 'kate',
    surname: 'post',
  }],
  id: '12364',
  weight: '50',
  Oid: '456978',
  code: '12',
}, {
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
    name: 'jane',
    // This value is different
    surname: 'FOOL',
  }, {
    name: 'kate',
    surname: 'post',
  }],
  id: '4589632',
  weight: 50,
  policy: '745896',
  result: 'test',
  documents: 'no',
  launch: 'no',
}, [
  'name',
  'surname',
  'reference',
  'weight',
]));

// Position is different - should work
console.log(compareObjects({
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
      name: 'jane',
      surname: 'smith',
      position: 10,
    },
    {
      name: 'kate',
      surname: 'post',
      position: 10,
    },
  ],
  id: '12364',
  weight: '50',
  Oid: '456978',
  code: '12',
}, {
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
    name: 'jane',
    surname: 'smith',
    position: 10,
  }, {
    name: 'kate',
    surname: 'post',
    position: 15,
  }],
  id: '4589632',
  weight: 50,
  policy: '745896',
  result: 'test',
  documents: 'no',
  launch: 'no',
}, [
  'name',
  'surname',
  'reference',
  'weight',
]));

// Everything is same - should work (including position)
console.log(compareObjects({
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
      name: 'jane',
      surname: 'smith',
      position: 10,
    },
    {
      name: 'kate',
      surname: 'post',
      position: 10,
    },
  ],
  id: '12364',
  weight: '50',
  Oid: '456978',
  code: '12',
}, {
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'doe',
  reference: [{
    name: 'jane',
    surname: 'smith',
    position: 10,
  }, {
    name: 'kate',
    surname: 'post',
    position: 10,
  }],
  id: '4589632',
  weight: 50,
  policy: '745896',
  result: 'test',
  documents: 'no',
  launch: 'no',
}, [
  'name',
  'surname',
  'reference',
  'weight',
]));
```

Comment: this works great, but i only realised now in my nested array "reference" i have another array imbedded into it as {name:"test",surname:"test",array:[name:"array1",position:"2"]}, how would i incorporate the imbedded array from the nested array into the function?

Comment: So you want to compare the `position` as well?

Comment: yep,everything thats within the imbedded "array"

Answer (score 0):

For the given scenario/example a reliable and even recommended approach was to provide a custom *stringify* function which unifies/normalizes any provided object structure (they might differ amongst objects) and also sanitizes any of an object's value type (which does e.g. differ amongst the object examples provided by the OP), and then does return a string representative of this very object.

Objects which were processed in such a way then safely can be compared to one another ...

```js
const objA = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "doe",
  reference: [{
    name: "jane", surname: "smith", array: [
      { position: 12, surname: "test", name: "test" }
    ]
  }, {
    name: "kate", surname:"post", array:[
      { name: "test", surname: "test", position: 12 }
    ]
  }],
  id: "12364",
  weight: "50",
  Oid: "456978",
  code: "12",
};
const objB = {
  reference: [{
    surname:"post", name: "kate", array:[
      { name: "test", surname: "test", position: 12 }
    ]
  }, {
    array: [
      { name: "test", surname: "test", position: 12 }
    ],
    name: "jane",
    surname: "smith",
  }],
  surname: "doe",
  name: "John",
  id: "4589632",
  weight: 50,
  policy: "745896",
  result: "test",
  documents: "no",
  launch: "no",
};

const objC = {
  name: "John", surname: "doe",
  reference: [{
    name: "jane", surname: "smith", array: [
      { position: 12, surname: "test", name: "test" }
  ]}, {
    name: "kate", surname:"post", array:[
      { name: "test", surname: "test", position: 12 }
    ]
  }],
  weight: "60",
};
const objD = {
  name: "John", surname: "doe",
  reference: [{
    name: "jane", surname: "smith", array: [
      { position: 12, surname: "test", name: "test" }
  ]}, {
    name: "kate", surname:"post", array:[
      { name: "test", surname:"test", position: 24 }
    ]
  }],
  weight: "60",
};

const orderByName = (a, b) =>
  a.surname.localeCompare(b.surname) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);

function normalizeItemReference(arr) {
  return arr
    // assure a certain order.
    .sort(orderByName)
    // assure identical structure. 
    .map(({ name, surname, array }) =>
      ({
        name,
        surname,
        array: array
          // assure a certain order.
          .sort(orderByName)
          // assure identical structure and value type.
          .map(({ name, surname, position }) =>
            ({ name, surname, position: Number(position) })
          )
      })
    );
}
function stringifyItem(obj) {
  const { name, surname, weight, reference } = obj;
  return JSON.stringify({
    // assure identical structure and value types.
    name,
    surname,
    weight: Number(weight),
    reference: normalizeItemReference(reference)
  });
}

console.log(
  '(stringifyItem(objA) === stringifyItem(objB)) ?',
  (stringifyItem(objA) === stringifyItem(objB))
);
console.log(
  '(stringifyItem(objA) === stringifyItem(objC)) ?',
  (stringifyItem(objA) === stringifyItem(objC))
);
console.log(
  '(stringifyItem(objC) === stringifyItem(objD)) ?',
  (stringifyItem(objC) === stringifyItem(objD))
);

console.log(
  'stringifyItem(objA) ...',
  stringifyItem(objA)
);
console.log(
  'stringifyItem(objB) ...',
  stringifyItem(objB)
);
console.log(
  'stringifyItem(objC) ...',
  stringifyItem(objC)
);
console.log(
  'stringifyItem(objD) ...',
  stringifyItem(objD)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```